# rspec - why does this array key comparison fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, matcher

```
Failure/Error: @group.attributes.keys.should include (Group.first.attributes.keys)     
   expected 

["id", "duration", "frequency", "period", "group_size", "location", "service", "area_of_need", "created_at", "updated_at", "therapist_id", "start_date", "end_date", "student_id", "adhoc"] 
to include  
["id", "duration", "frequency", "period", "group_size", "location", "service", "area_of_need", "created_at", "updated_at", "therapist_id", "start_date", "end_date", "student_id", "adhoc"]
```

Test:

```
@group.attributes.keys.should include (Group.first.attributes.keys)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te answer was that the hash comparison fails on Ubuntu but works on Mac's.

My workaround is:

```
i=0
  while i < @group.attributes.count
  assert_equal @group.attributes[i], Group.first.attributes[i]
  i+= 1
end

# Comparing field by field as ruby hash comparison isn't working right - 
# but only on Ubuntu!
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `a.should includes(b)` asserts that `a.include? b` is true and`include?` checks to see if an array's elements includes an object, not whether one array equals another

```
[1].include? [1]
=> false

[1].include? 1
=> true

[[1]].include? [1]
=> true
```